# ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Tags: python, string, file

I am new to python and I am trying make a program that reads a file, and puts the information in its own vectors. the file is an xyz file that looks like this:

```
45 

Fe -0.055 0.033 -0.047
N -0.012 -1.496 1.451
N 0.015 -1.462 -1.372
N 0.000 1.386 1.481
N 0.070 1.417 -1.339
C -0.096 -1.304 2.825
C 0.028 -1.241 -2.739
C -0.066 -2.872 1.251
C -0.0159 -2.838 -1.205
```

Starting from the 3rd line I need to place each in its own vectors, so far I have this:

```
file=open("Question4.xyz","r+")
A = []
B = []
C = []
D = []
counter=0
for line in file:
    if counter>2: #information on particles start on the 2nd line
        a,b,c,d=line.split()
        A.append(a)
        B.append(float(b))
        C.append(float(c))
        D.append(float(d))
    counter=counter+1
```

I am getting this error:

```
 File "<pyshell#72>", line 3, in <module>
    a,b,c,d=line.split()
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is that 45 at the first line of your file?? Does your file start from there??

Comment: 45 is apart of the file but im only concerned with the information from line 3 and down

Comment: out of interest, why are you creating lists of X and Y coords separately (accessed as `B[15] C[15] D[15]` etc), rather than a list of `[x,y,z]` vectors that you can perform calculations on as objects themselves? as @sberry said, I also wouldn't bother unpacking the values into local variables as you do; it's just extra, unnecessary code when you can catch the split (list) into a `tokens` variable and access with `tokens[1:]` (or better still `[float(t) for t in tokens[1:]]` for the vector representation I mentioned.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have lines in your that doesn't actually result in 4 items on splitting. Add a condition for that.

```
for line in file:
    spl = line.strip().split()
    if len(spl) == 4:  # this will take care of both empty lines and 
                       # lines containing greater than or less than four items
        a, b, c, d = spl
        A.append(a)
        B.append(float(b))
        C.append(float(c))
        D.append(float(d))
```

Comment: Thanks - those extra additions will help

Comment: And... what if `len(spl) != 4`? Your just skipping the line, without knowing it. Better let your code whine.

Comment: then you can add anything in the `else` part, handle that line in `else` part.

Answer (score 0):

Would you happen to have an empty line somewhere, by any chance (or with only a `'\n'`) ?

You could force

```
if counter >= 2:
    if line.strip():
        (a,b,c,d) = line.strip().split()
```

An advantage of **not** checking whether your split line has a `len` of 4 is that it won't silently skip the line if it doesn't have the right number of fields (like you experienced yourself with the empty lines at the end of your files): you'll get an exception instead, which forces you to double-check your input (or your logic).

Comment: this will fail for the first line containing `'45'`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary This won't, as `counter = 0` in that case.

Comment: return type of function does not match with values expected in function...

check the number of variables returned from function and variables you are expecting