# Adding different data to different dictionaries from a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So, I have a text file which looks like:

```
AUD_CHF 0.77324
AUD_EUR 0.72657
AUD_GBP 0.61557
AUD_JPY 86.88
AUD_USD 0.76835
CAD_EUR 0.722459831
CAD_GBP 0.612726326
CAD_CHF 0.76915
CHF_EUR 0.939858457
CHF_GBP 0.795924865
```

What I want to do is read through it and put each currency into it's own dictionary eg.
 `AUD {AUD_CHF: 0.77324, AUD_EUR :0.72657 AUD_GBP :0.61557 AUD_JPY :6.88, AUD_USD :0.76835}` 
then CHF, USD etc. There will be 18 dictionaries when finished. I've managed to do this with the folowing code (with some help on another question) but it is long and not very pythonic as I understand it. It looks like this

```
USD = {}
AUD = {}
CHF = {}
with open('rates.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        split_line = line.split()
        if line.startswith('USD'):
            USD[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]
        elif line.startswith('AUD'):
            AUD[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]
        elif line.startswith('CHF'):
            CHF[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]
```

I mean, it works but I can't imagaine there isn't a better way. I spoke to a friend and he suggested a solution, it used vars(), local() and from what I read that's not a great thing and I couldn't get it to work the way I wanted. I was thinking a loop of some kind but I can't get anything going. If anyone has any ideas for me to try I would be grateful. Even if it only a skeleton so I can go and try to make it work.

Thanks for your time, apologies this is a bit long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a dictionary of dictionaries and some defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
currencies = defaultdict(dict)

with open('rates.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       if line:
          currency, rate = line.split()
          currencies[currency[:3]][currency] = rate
```

Resulting in:

```
In [39]: currencies['AUD']
Out[39]:
{'AUD_CHF': '0.77324',
 'AUD_EUR': '0.72657',
 'AUD_GBP': '0.61557',
 'AUD_JPY': '86.88',
 'AUD_USD': '0.76835'}

In [40]: currencies['CHF']
Out[40]: {'CHF_EUR': '0.939858457', 'CHF_GBP': '0.795924865'}

In [41]: currencies['CAD']
Out[41]: {'CAD_CHF': '0.76915', 'CAD_EUR': '0.722459831', 'CAD_GBP': '0.612726326'}
```

Edit.

If you have lines that do not comply with space separation, you can try a try/except block amongst other things:

```
from collections import defaultdict
currencies = defaultdict(dict)

with open('rates.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       if line:
          try:
              currency, rate = line.split()
          except ValueError:
               # good practice to log here, if you were to have logging.
               continue #skip to next line
          currencies[currency[:3]][currency] = rate
```

Comment: I had never heard of defaultdic. I have some reading to do, thank you, so much to learn.
I entered it and got  'ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack' from line 7. Based on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891813/valueerror-need-more-than-0-values-to-unpack-python-lists) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687158/valueerror-need-more-than-0-values-to-unpack) (or is it something I have done?) I changed it and it runs through. 'print currencies' doesn't return dictionaries also I'm unsure how you got your "resulting in". Thanks again, really appreciate your time.

Comment: @pale see edit, one of your lines does not comply with the `first second` space separated, which is what it expects. `currencies` will not have anything if running into this.

Comment: The data set I had created had two duplicates which was causing the error. I googled that error and at no stage did it suggest that it was from bad data.... that's how you learn I guess. @salparadise your code is so succinct.... I had stuff everywhere. Thanks again for helping me out.